# WordPress qtranslate display post of some language

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

For example I have 2 languages: `EN` and RU: how to display in index.php post only in `RU` language ? maybe are some parameters in `wp_query` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use qtranslate core function

```
function qtrans_use($lang, $text, $show_available=false)
```

Something like this:

```
$mypost = get_post(get_the_ID()); 
$content = qtrans_use('ru', $mypost->post_content,false); 
echo "$content";
```

Comment: What if we need to query certain language posts? 'lang' in wp_query does not work as with other language plugins ... We don't need direct translation of content, just query certain language posts ..

Comment: As I remember the qTranslate plugin stores all the translations in the same post fields and then simply filters the content depending on the currently selected language. So simply query the post you want and then filter the result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

In new versions of qtranslate and qtranslate-x will work only as follows:

```
$postId = get_the_ID();

wp_cache_delete($postId, 'posts');
$mypost = WP_Post::get_instance($postId);

$titleEn = qtrans_use('en', $mypost->post_title, false);
$titleRu = qtrans_use('ru', $mypost->post_title, false);
//or all object:
$mypost = qtrans_use('en', $mypost, false);
```

See more about it (rus): https://intsystem.org/coding/qtranslate-x-vyvod-stati-v-drugom-yazyke/